# Is space legal after an angle bracket?

Tags: html, xml

I'm building a slicer for deserializing html and xml. The question is - is it legal in either language to put a space after angle bracket and still have it count as a tag? For example

```
< div>
```

Or should I just consider that plain text?

And yes, I tried searching web for this but even after browsing through w3, I couldn't spot an explicit answer.

Comment: Are you... Trying to do this with regex?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags) from WHATWG indicates the opening bracket must be immediately followed by the tag name.

The [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) from W3C has the same requirements.

You may not have space leading the tag name. However, there can be any amount of space between the end of the tag name and the closing bracket. The following is valid:

```
<p           ></p         >
<p
></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

No this is not legal,

For example this,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hey sup man</h1>
< div><p>hey sup</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

outputs this to the browser,

```
Hey sup man

< div>
hey sup
```